# nodejs - every minute, on the minute

Tags: node.js

How can I wait for a specific system time before firing ?

I want to fire an event when seconds = 0, i.e. every minute

```
while (1==1) {
    var date = new Date();
    var sec = date.getSeconds();
    if(sec===0) {
        Do Something()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't do that, because with this `while` you will have a blocking operation. Also, there are better things to do in any JavaScript platform, like using `setInterval`/`setTimeout` functions.
The node docs for them are [here](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html).

A quick example of how to achieve what you want:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  if ( date.getSeconds() === 0 ) {
    DoSomething();
  }
}, 1000);
```

For a more fine grained control over scheduled processes in Node, maybe you should checkout [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron/).

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the setInterval and setTimeout but didn't realize that you could use it in that way. How can I ensure that the event only fires one time as it will likely keep firing for 1 second ?

Comment: Yes, it's simple when you know how, seems very obvious now. Thanks so much.

Comment: @crankshaft it should be pointed out that `setInterval` makes no promises about returning in 1000ms. It could return earlier as a result of a system interrupt. It could return significantly later if the system is busy. In fact checking once every 1000ms will almost certainly "miss" from time to time if, as expected, the process wakes up slightly later than requested. It is not unusual to poll twice a second in this situation (think Nyquist Theorem) to ensure you sample fast enough to ensure a "hit".